# Laravel 5.2 ACL how to have multiple permissions with the same name and avoid having one role per user

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, acl

Okay, so I'm trying to implement an ACL using Laravel on an Intranet and I'm having some problems with permissions growing rapidly out of control. So first off, here's what I've got:

My five tables defining my users, my roles and my permissions like this:

```
tblIntranetUser
UserID
Name
FirstName
Username

tblIntranetRoles
RoleID
RoleName
Description

tblIntranetPermissions
PermissionID
PermissionName
Description

tblIntranetRoles_Permissions
RoleID
PermissionID

tblIntranetUsers_Roles
UserID
RoleID
```

And also I have the AuthServiceProvider as well as the Permission and Role models:

```
class Permission extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tblIntranetPermissions';

    protected $primaryKey = 'PermissionID';

    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['PermissionID', 'PermissionName', 'Description'];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'tblIntranetRoles_Permissions', 'PermissionID', 'RoleID');
    }

    public function detachAllRoles()
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        foreach($roles as $role){
           $role->permissions()->detach($this);
        }
    }
}

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tblIntranetRoles';

    protected $primaryKey = 'RoleID';

    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['RoleID', 'RoleName', 'Description'];


    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission', 'tblIntranetRoles_Permissions', 'RoleID', 'PermissionID');
    }

    public function givePermissionTo(Permission $permission)
    {
        return $this->permissions()->save($permission);
    }

    public function getUsers()
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('UserID')->get();
        $roleusers = collect();

        foreach($users as $user){
            if($user->hasRole($this->name)){
                $roleusers->push($user);
            }
        }
        return $roleusers;
    }

    public function detachAllUsers()
    {
        $users = $this->getUsers();
        foreach($users as $user){
            $user->roles()->detach($this);   
        }
    }

    public function detachAllPermissions()
    {
        $permissions = $this->permissions;
        foreach($permissions as $permission){
           $permission->roles()->detach($this);
        }
    }
}

namespace App\Providers;
use App\Report, App\Permission;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [

    ];
    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate  $gate
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        $this->registerPolicies($gate);

        foreach ($this->getPermissions() as $permission){

            $gate->before(function ($user) {
                if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            $gate->define($permission->name, function($user) use ($permission){
                return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
            });
        }
    }

    protected function getPermissions()
    {
        return Permission::with('roles')->get();
    }
}
```

So, thanks to this, I was able to create various roles and assign permissions to them which allows them to access certain sections of the Intranet as well as see certain reports. For example, I can define the following:

```
Role: Analyst
Access: Section 1, 2, 3
Reports: 1,15,41

Role: Developer
Access: All sections
Reports: All reports
```

It would be fine if every analyst could see and access the same sections... but of course that's not the case. Same goes for developers. Following this model, it basically means I need to have one role for every user as well as one permission for every possible element on the Intranet. Given that there's roughly 200 reports available as well as about 30 users, this makes for a lot of "show_report_1", "show_report_2", "show_section_1", "show_section_2" permissions (Laravel identifies permissions by name).

So, in order to make things a bit more... orderly I guess, I've been wondering if there wouldn't be a way to have one permission named "show_report" with the reportID stored in another field and to avoid having one role per user.

Comment: Row-level security? Isn't that for Databases? I'm trying to give access to particular elements of an Intranet

Comment: You could add another data structure and table for `tblIntranetPermissionsLists`, which would be a list of `tblIntranetPermissions`. It would have a one to many relationship like 1 TIPL can reference M TIP.

Comment: That is actually a pretty decent idea. It doesn't remove the need to have one role per user, but it can still make permissions a bit more manageable.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need one role per user. Roles are sets of Permission Lists. Permission Lists are sets of Single Permissions. Single Permissions target one resource (page, section, report). Users can have 0-M Roles. Right?

Comment: Well, because every user has a different set of permissions. So every user will need its own permission list custom-made for him... hence, every user needs its own role

Comment: Hmmm that was unavoidable though correct?

Comment: Yeah... we tried to reason with the client, but he's adamant about being able to define EXACTLY what each of his users can and cannot see.

Comment: I did use this component in the past, to have users in groups, and permissions on both. Take a look: https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1#groups

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the "proper" way to do this, but you could add an extra row to one of your pivot tables (probably the role_permission one) and use that to store more specific data about the permission. (eg. sections they can access)

Check out here for accessing pivot values: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

```
$role = App\Role::find(1);

foreach ($role->permissions as $permission) {
    echo $permission->pivot->permission_settings; // [1,2,3]
}
```

That way you could have a single permission of "access_section", and then just check the pivot to see what sections they can access.

(There is probably a better or 'proper' way to do this though)